# Google translate v3 hanging when deployed to App Engine Flex Python

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-translate

I've built a single wrapper for translating text using `google.cloud` `translate_v3`

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate
from google.cloud.translate_v3 import types
from credentials import credentials
from typing import Optional


class Translator:
    def __init__(self):
        project_name = credentials.project_id
        self.client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()
        self.parent = f"projects/{project_name}/locations/global"

    def translate(self, text: str, source: str, target: str) -> Optional[str]:
        try:
            request = types.TranslateTextRequest()
            request.parent = self.parent
            request.source_language_code = source
            request.target_language_code = target
            request.contents = [text]
            request.mime_type = "text/plain"

            print("Translator: translate_text start")
            response = self.client.translate_text(request=request)
            print("Translator: got response")

            for translation in response.translations:
                print(f"Translated text: {translation.translated_text}")

            if len(response.translations) < 1:
                return text

            print("Translator: translate_text complete")
            return response.translations[0].translated_text

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception during translation: {e}")
            return text
```

This has been working fine whilst building on my local machine, however deploying it to my app engine flex instance it doesn't..

I've added the `Cloud Translation API User` role to my App Engine service account, and I'm getting absolutely no feedback... it actually seems to crash the App Engine.

Calling...

```
print(f"Translating text: {text} from {raw_source} to {raw_target}")
translation = self.translator.translate(text, raw_source, raw_target)
```

Locally...

```
Translating text: testing locally from en to ja
Translator: translate_text start
Translator: got response
Translated text: ローカルでのテスト
Translator: translate_text complete
```

Deployed...

```
Translating text: test deployed from en to ja
Translator: translate_text start
```

Then nothing.. no exception, no warnings, everything dies.

I've tried moving `client` inside the method...

i.e.

```
request = types.TranslateTextRequest()
request.parent = self.parent
request.source_language_code = source
request.target_language_code = target
request.contents = [text]
request.mime_type = "text/plain"
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

print("Translator: translate_text start")
response = client.translate_text(request=request)
print("Translator: got response")
```

and i've tried removing `request.mime_type = "text/plain"`

both with no success